# Hide Fallback image on Desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, responsive

I am working on this [website](http://www.lhommecirque-film.ch)   and i am using a mp4 Video as Background, as you can see.

This BG Video does not works on mobile and for this i have to use a **Fallback Image**.

The problem is that on page load this image is visible for 1 or 2 second. Is possible to hide it completely on Desktops?

Any tips?

Comment: You could hide the entire element until the video has loaded, then unhide it.

Comment: The stack overflow community strictly recommends that you create a JSFiddle instead of giving us links to your sites. Can you please make the change so that the community standards are followed.

Answer (score 0):

USE CSS3 Media Queries to remove the background as below

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
    #idOfElementToHide {
        background-image: none !important; // assuming that you are using inline styles you'll have to add !important to make sure this overrides the inline styles
    }
}
```

Comment: And oh yes!! Do not forget that your stylesheet needs to load in head section of the page else it'll still try to load your background image and then remove it again